# Python code don’t work when launched by cron

Tags: python, sqlite, cron

I have a program which begin by the following code :

```
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

This code returns a tupple with the tables of the database. It works well when I run this manually, but not when I run it with cron (I use Debian Wheezy). When I launch it with cron, I have only `[]` as output, and I don’t understand why. Any idea ? Thanks.

EDIT : the rest of the code work fine, even when launched by cron.

EDITbis : here is the complete code

```
# Opening of the database
data="bdd-test.sq3"
conn =sqlite3.connect(data)
cur =conn.cursor()

type_liste=[]
table_liste=[]
# Listing and opening of the tables
cur.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
print(cur.fetchall())

for table in cur.fetchall():
    table=table[0]
    if '_m' in table:
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (date TEXT, type TEXT, zone TEXT, min REAL, max REAL, moyenne REAL)".format(table))
    else:
        type_liste.append(table)
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {} (date TEXT, type TEXT, zone TEXT, value REAL)".format(table))
```

Comment: What is cur? How is it connected to your db?

Comment: `EDIT : the rest of the code work fine, even when launched by cron.` Please, let us decide that. As of now your given snippet does not give us enough information to troubleshoot the problem. The information on how `cur` is opened is absolutely __crucial__, but you have not given that.

Comment: Crystal ball suggestion: Path to DB connector libraries set in environment variable which cron will not see. (IIRC, cron uses an almost-naked environment, not the regular one of the user.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably it's because when launched from `cron` your current working directory is different, so you are not opening the right db file. And normally sqlite creates a new database file, empty and so the empty resultset of your snippet.

Try to specify your database file with an absolute path istead of relative (as i'm guessing you're doing).

**UPDATE**: yes, reading the full example you just posted I, you need to specify the full path in `data`.

Comment: It was that. Thanks !